# WebSocket through SSL with Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, proxy, reverse-proxy

On the client side, I am trying to establish the wss connection:

`var ws = new WebSocket("wss://wsserver.com/test")`

and it returns an error:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://wsserver.com/test' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

The full headers are:

**Request Headers**

```
GET wss://wsserver.com/test HTTP/1.1
Host: wsserver.com
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: https://website.net
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Tj9AJ5TKglNf5LoHsQTpvQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://website.net
Connection:close
Content-Length:18
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 21 Apr 2017 21:03:45 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Origin
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
```

The server side is running on go at port 8888 behind an Apache reverse proxy. This is the Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName website.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass "/" "wss://localhost:8888/"
```

*mod_proxy* and *mod_proxy_wstunnel* are installed.

Is there something missing here? It seems like the request goes through but no connection is established.

Comment: `lcalhost`? Is this a typo?

Comment: yes, indeed, this was a typo, but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by using this configuration for the virtual host, which filters requests using the HTTP headers:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName website.com

    RewriteEngine On

    # When Upgrade:websocket header is present, redirect to ws
    # Using NC flag (case-insensitive) as some browsers will pass Websocket
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/ws/(.*)    wss://localhost:8888/ws/$1 [P,L]

    # All other requests go to http
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8888/"
```

I'm leaving this as a reference in case it helps others

Comment: In my case it's a little bit tricky, Node-RED use /nodered/comms as EndPoint, so I have to change your rule to `RewriteRule ^/nodered/comms    wss://localhost:1880/nodered/comms [P,L]` .

Answer (score 6):

In order to place a secure reverse proxy server in front of an insecure websocket server, you could do this:

```apache
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:aNULL:eNULL:EXPORT:DES:RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain
    ServerName website.com
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)    ws://localhost:8888/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This will take a request inbound for **wss://website.com:443**, and reverse proxy it to **ws://localhost:8888**.

If the websocket server is also secure, you can simply change
**ws://localhost:8888** to
**wss://website.com:8888**

Comment: Thanks, its works. Moreover, its works without port, just wss://domain.net

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed to activate "SSLProxyEngine on" to make the whole thing works...

I ended up with this 2 lines solution on Debian / Apache 2.4 (used port is 4321)

```
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass         /wss  wss://127.0.0.1:4321/
```

Comment: I used your answer (changing `/wss` to `/path/I/wanted` and then `wss://` to `ws://`, used the RewriteEngine answer from @Andrei Savin and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is my setup of virtualhost that worked for me, I have .netcore app on docker with SignalR as a websocket service.

On `5000` my .netcore app is running, and on `/chatHub` my signalR listens.

Will be helpful for future comers with same problem.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  RewriteEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  # allow for upgrading to websockets
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:5000/$1 [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:5000/$1 [P,L]


  ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:5000/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:5000/"

  ProxyPass "/chatHub" "ws://localhost:5000/chatHub"
  ProxyPassReverse "/chatHub" "ws://localhost:5000/chatHub"

  ServerName site.com
  
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Source: http://shyammakwana.me/server/websockets-with-apache-reverse-proxy-with-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

@  pimgeek's Comment:

I think instead of
`RewriteRule ^/nodered/comms wss://localhost:1880/nodered/comms [P,L]`

you could have utilized $1 as follow:
`RewriteRule ^/nodered/comms$ wss://localhost:1880/$1 [P,L]`

Also, this should work aswell:
`RewriteRule ^/nodered/comms$ wss://localhost:1880$1 [P,L]`

Notice the not needed / after the port, since $1 includes already a / at the beginning

Comment: You are missing parentheses around `/nodered/comms`. Without there won't be the matching group (a.k.a. back-reference) 1 available. See following link for details: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex