# WebSocket error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: php, ssl, https, websocket, xampp

I've just create a PHP web server on local server, (Xampp environment, Windows) with Let's Encrypt SSL certificate (NOT SELF-SIGNED) so my website https://example.it looks like valid certificate with every browser.
I can navigate to it both with http:// and https:// with standard ports.

Now I'm implementing php socket for creating web chat, however if I use insecure web socket protocol over HTTP:

**ws://example.it:8090/chat/php-socket.php**

it works.

If I use secure web socket protocol over HTTPS:

**wss://example.it:8090/chat/php-socket.php**

I receive an error on establishing connection net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This is my code if someone needs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://example.it:8090/chat/php-socket.php");
        websocket.onopen = function(event) {
            showMessage("<div class='chat-connection-ack'>Connssione stabilita.</div>");
        }
        websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
            var Data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(Data);
            showMessage("<div class='"+Data.message_type+"'>"+Data.message+"</div>");
            $('#chat-message').val('');
        };
});
```

Comment: include cert in your code https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html this example will help : https://github.com/websockets/ws

Comment: @Dilek I can only use https, so no need to validate it.
My Js object "WebSocket" don't have options to include cert .pem

Comment: As I said in firt comment requiers SSL_PROTOCOL. Here is your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404160/why-does-my-wss-websockets-over-ssl-tls-connection-immediately-disconnect-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the same port (8090) for `ws://` and `wss://` - this will most likely not work. While you don't show any server side configuration I suspect that your websocket server on port 8090 can only do plain WebSockets (i.e. `ws://` and not `wss://`) and that you expect the TLS from the HTTP server (port 443) to be magically applied to `wss://` on port 8090 too. This is not the case. By trying `wss://` with port 8090 you are instead trying to do a TLS handshake with a server which does not speak TLS, which then results in `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

The common setup is instead to use a web server like nginx or Apache as reverse proxy for the websocket server and terminate the TLS at the web server. This way both `ws://` and `wss://` work on the standard ports (i.e. 80 and 443) from outside and the internet plain websocket server on port 8090 is will be made unreachable from outside. See for example [NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss) or [WebSocket through SSL with Apache reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552164/websocket-through-ssl-with-apache-reverse-proxy) for how to setup something like this.

Comment: what did you do?